# Default type of prop depending on the value of another prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have this component which can cater single-select or multiselect feature. If multiselect is true, the initialValue should be an empty array. Else, it should be an empty object. Setting defaultProps looks a little complicated with this scenario. Is there any way I can set default prop of `initialValue` depending on the value of `multiselect`?

```
const wrap = compose(
  setPropTypes({
    initialValue: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.array]),
    multiselect: PropTypes.bool,
  }),
  defaultProps({
    initialValue: // [] or {} or ((otherProps) => otherProps.multiselect ? [] : {}) ??? , if there is such thing
    multiselect: false,
  })
);
```

If I set it as `{}`, the user could still pass `multiselect={true}` without passing defaultValue. In this case, several functions will `map` through defaultValue whereas it's not an array, resulting to improper handling of data plus numerous errors.

The same would happen if I just carelessly assume other scenarios. Is there any perfect approach for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Small side note, but I think you should be using `PropTypes.oneOfType` instead of `oneOf`

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't have the `multiselect` property. Because you already have this information (it will be a multiselect component if the `initialValue` is of type array, otherwise it will not be multiselect). Therefore it seems that the `multiselect` property is redundant.

Comment: @sme Sorry. It should be `PropTypes,oneOfType`. My bad. However, I can't do your suggestion. I think it's pretty odd to read a documentation where you can see a component's multiselect feature be dependent on `initialValue` prop, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In plain language, it is not possible. I had the same dilema in a few components of mine. My suggest is to use two properties, one per each select type. Besides, you can remove the multiselect property and check it watching which of the two properties I mentioned is not null. In short:

```
const wrap = compose(
  setPropTypes({
    initialSingleValue: PropTypes.object,
    initialMultiValue: PropTypes.array,
  }),
  defaultProps({
    initialSingleValue: {}
    initialMultiValue: nil,
  })
);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: It definitely makes sense.